# How to return to root ViewController, if the current is deeply nested?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem that my iOS app has several `ViewControllers`.

For example: ViewControllers named like `A`, `B`, `C`. `A` jumped to `B` with `pushViewController`, `B` jumped to `C` with `presentViewController` , `C` jumped to `D` with `presentViewController` and so on.

If the current ViewController is `Z` or some other ViewController, how can I jump back to `A` directly?

Comment: Have a loot at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: are you useing navigationController or not ?

Comment: @iGodric Thanks for editing , my English is really very poor.. ;)

Comment: Thanks to everyones patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Below code. It will work for all cases :**

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[nameOfYourViewControllerYouWantToNavigate class]])
        {
            if(controller.isBeingPresented)
                 [controller.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
            else
                 [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];

            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , let me have a try~

Comment: @Tanddd If the answer is working then please accept it. This is motivation for us.

Comment: Sorry for forgeting to accept.In the situation described before, the code won't  work because of too much 'presentViewController' and  'pushViewController'. Finally, I've  resolved it by adding a return function to Base VC. Thanks for your help~~

Comment: Hard to read my words, isn't it ?  Thanks to everyones patience, I think maybe I haven't describe my problem clearly because of my poor english, but there are still so many people who give me advice. Also, I wish I could  share my solution, but my english is really bad that I might not describe it clearly. Haha...I will update the code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It will pop your viewcontroller to Root controller.

Comment: It's not working  while there is a presented viewcontroller here~

Answer (score 0):

For the view controllers show by `pushViewController`, you can get rootViewController via `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]`
Others shown by `presentViewController`, you can get parent view controller via `self.presentingViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to go back to A ViewController from any other view controller, first you have to set that as `RootViewController`. If you use XIB you must set as root in app delegate `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` method. If you use storyboard you should set `NavigationController` in storyboard and set AViewController as ROOT using control+drag(mouse).
I work in a project which has lot of view controllers. It has `pushViewController` and `PresentViewControllers` also I set A as`RootViewController`. So I can return from any view controller to RootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     AViewController *aVC = [[AViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@“AViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aVC];
     self.window.rootViewController = aVC;
     [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
}
```

For going to AViewController from any other view controller

```
- (IBAction)actionGoBack:(id)sender 
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```